# ArcObjects 10.1 Misplaced graticule labels after map export to jpeg

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, grids-graticules

I´m currently working on an ArcObject 10.1 Extension which 'produces a Map' and exports it´s Page Layout to 'jpeg' after completion. The code follows the snippet for 'Create JPEG (high-resolution) from ActiveView':

```c#
     public static System.Boolean CreateJPEGHiResolutionFromActiveView(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView activeView, System.String pathFileName, short shortQuality, int intResolution)
    {
        pathFileName = pathFileName.Replace(".jpeg", ".jpg");

        //parameter check
        if (activeView == null || !(pathFileName.EndsWith(".jpg")))
        {
            return false;
        }
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.IExport export = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Output.ExportJPEGClass();
        export.ExportFileName = pathFileName;

        IExportJPEG pExportJPEG = export as IExportJPEG;
        pExportJPEG.Quality = shortQuality;

        // Because we are exporting to a resolution that differs from screen 
        // resolution, we should assign the two values to variables for use 
        // in our sizing calculations
        System.Int32 screenResolution = 96;
        System.Int32 outputResolution = intResolution;

        export.Resolution = outputResolution;

        ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.tagRECT exportRECT; // This is a structure
        exportRECT.left = 0;
        exportRECT.top = 0;
        exportRECT.right = activeView.ExportFrame.right * (outputResolution / screenResolution);
        exportRECT.bottom = activeView.ExportFrame.bottom * (outputResolution / screenResolution);

        // Set up the PixelBounds envelope to match the exportRECT
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IEnvelope envelope = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.EnvelopeClass();
        envelope.PutCoords(exportRECT.left, exportRECT.top, exportRECT.right, exportRECT.bottom);
        export.PixelBounds = envelope;

        System.Int32 hDC = export.StartExporting();

        activeView.Output(hDC, (System.Int16)export.Resolution, ref exportRECT, null, null); // Explicit Cast and 'ref' keyword needed 
        export.FinishExporting();
        export.Cleanup();

        return true;
    } // end of CreateJPEGHiResolutionFromActiveView
```

After export it occurs from time to time that the graticule labels are displaced, whereas they are at the correct position in the Layout of ArcMap.

[image: labels positioned as desired in active Pagelayout]

[image: displaced labels after Export to jpeg]

[image: labels positioned as desired in active Pagelayout]

[image: displaced labels after Export to jpeg]

Does anybody has a hint for me what could be the cradle of this mess and how to work around this Problem?